# Pentaho check if at least one row LDAP is 0

Tags: javascript, pentaho

I have multiple rows in `Pentaho` with Column name "LDAP flag"

| Column | user id | LDAP flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Row 1 | A | 1 |
| Row 2 | B | 1 |
| Row 3 | B | 0 |

I need rows like below:

| Column | user id | LDAP flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Row 1 | A | 1 |
| Row 3 | B | 0 |

If at least one row is `0` then I need to set "LDAP check" to `True`

| Column | user id | LDAP flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Row 1 | C | 1 |
| Row 2 | C | 1 |
| Row 3 | C | 1 |

If all rows equal `1` then I need to set "LDAP check" to `False`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always in PDI, you can do this in various ways. This is just one of the ways to accomplished this.

You can use the *Group by* step:

- Mark the check to retrieve all rows instead of only the grouped rows
- You don't group by any row, so all the rows are involved in the sums and counts.
- You calculate two values with your grouping rows:

  - You sum the value of the column LDAP flag for all rows. I name this column *SumFlag* in my screenshot.
  - You count all rows. *SumRows* in my screenshot.
- You use a *Formula* step to calculate a new column (*NewLDAPflag* in my screenshot) with value 0 if *SumFlag* is 0 or is equal to *SumRows*, and value 1  in any other case.
- I haven't added it to my screenshot, but if you want as final result only two columns, the original **Column** and the **LDAP flag** with the new value, you can use the *Select values* step to select the columns you want and rename as needed.

[image: Transformation schema]

This is the configuration of the Group by step:
[image: Configuration of the Group by step]

And this of the Formula step:
[image: Configuration of the Formula step]

Comment: I have field Attribute Data List and It is holding the value like BMC.ADDM:1,2,3,5,6,7,8,112,179,200000001,200000003, , I want to check value only BMC:ADD:8  , Which Step I should use in Pentoho

Comment: This is another question, so by StackOverflow rules you should open a new question. Besides, comments don't allow formatting or adding images, which I think is part of the problem why I don't understand what you're asking now. Better clarify it in a new question, putting on all the relevant details even if they are repeated, so people with your same problem or providing solutions can find all the details in one place.